# Не работают комментарии WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Не могу разобраться как создать кастомную форму для отправки комментариев без привязки к стандартной, поискал по интернету нашел необходимую структуру переделал под себя но комментарии не добавляются  пишет ошибку все время

```
<form class="order" id="forma_zhlb" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Оставить отзыв</h2>
            <input type="hidden" name="send_review">
            <table class="order">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <label>Имя</label>
                        <input name="name_zhlb" id="name_zhlb" class="text" type="text" value="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Телефон *</label>
                        <input name="phone" id="number" class="text phone" placeholder="+7(___)___-__-__" type="tel" required="true">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label style="padding-left: 9px;">Номер договора</label>
                        <input name="document_no_zhlb" id="document_no" class="text" type="text" value="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <label>Почта</label>
                        <input name="email_zhlb" id="email" class="text">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="txtarea">
                        <label>Отзыв *</label>
                        <textarea name="review_zhlb" class="text" id="review" required="true" ></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input class="submit form_bottom_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            <div class="hint-review">
                Нажимая на кнопку «Отправить», вы подтверждаете своё совершеннолетие и соглашаетесь
                на обработку персональных данных в соответствии с <a href="#privacy" class="fancybox" >условиями</a>.
            </div>
            <?php comment_id_fields();
            do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
        </form>
```

Comment: А ошибку мы должны угадать?

Comment: Без привязки к "стандартным? O_o Мсье махохист или фантазёр? Или просто вопрос не умеет поставить?